# Button needs to be clicked twice before working, I want it to be clicked just once

Tags: javascript, jquery, codeigniter

I have a enable and disable button. Each buttons returns a "success" message in the console when clicked. The enable button works in a single click, however, the disable button needs to be clicked twice before it prints the "success" message in the console in my developer tools. What is the problem with this? Can somebody helps me fixing this one? Thanks a lot. Here is my code:

```
 <button  class="btn_mode"  value="1">Enable</button>
 <button  class="btn_mode"  value="0">Disable</button>


  <script type="text/javascript">

$(".btn_mode").click(function(){

  var mode_val = $(this).val();
  var postdata={'mode':mode_val};

  $.ajax({

    type:"POST",
    url:"<?php echo base_url();?>superadmin/change_mode",
    dataType:'json',
    data:postdata,
    success: function(data){

         if(data.notify=="Success")
            {
             console.log(data.notify);
             location.reload();
            }
            else{
              console.log(data.notify);

            }

       }
  });

});



</script>
```

my controller function

```
function change_mode(){

  $mode = $this->input->post('mode');
  $query = $this->course_booking_model->change_mode($mode);

  if($query){
    $notification = "Success";
   }
  else{
   $notification = "Failed";
   }

   echo json_encode(array('notify'=>$notification));

   }
```

model

```
function change_mode($mode){

  $id = 1;

   $data = array('mode' => $mode);

   $this->db->where('id',$id);
   $this->db->update('maintenance_mode',$data);

   return true;
  }
```

Output when adding the `console.log('Posting mode_val: ' + mode_val);` in the javascript
Clicking the enable button output in the console

[image]
Output in the console when clicking the disable button

[image]

Comment: Without the 'return false' .. is it working now ?

Comment: What does your PHP script do? Maybe you get an error the first time?

Comment: The event u have intialized will trigger two times as both buttons have same class need to initiate separate events for buttons...

Comment: I tried to change the class of the disable button so that they wouldn't have the same class but still not working

Comment: @codebreaker. What do you mean? It does not initiate twice if you click on one button.

Comment: The disable button needs to be clicked twice before it prints success in the console

Comment: The disable button needs to be clicked twice before it prints success in the console. I want it to be clicked just once to make it work

Comment: Have you checked the Network tab of your browser's developer tools to ensure that no AJAX request is even being made on the first click?

Comment: I checked it, it was being executed but the problem is it doesn't work in the console, it doesn't print the message "success" and it takes two clicks before it executes the reload function

Comment: Why does your model always return true?

Answer (score 1):

As your event hook-up looks fine, i suspect that something is going wrong on the server side, which means that your success handler isn't firing. Try logging prior to your ajax call, to see if the click event fires at all:

```
$(".btn_mode").click(function(){

  var mode_val = $(this).val();
  var postdata={'mode':mode_val};

  console.log('Posting mode_val: ' + mode_val);

  $.ajax({

    type:"POST",
    url:"<?php echo base_url();?>superadmin/change_mode",
    dataType:'json',
    data:postdata,
    success: function(data){

         if(data.notify=="Success")
            {
             console.log(data.notify);
             location.reload();
            }
            else{
              console.log(data.notify);

            }

       }
  });

});
```

If the above logs the expected values when you click the buttons, that means that your php script is failing the first time you call it with `mode_val = 0`.

You could try catching whatever exception might be thrown like so:

```
function change_mode(){
  try{
      $mode = $this->input->post('mode');
      $query = $this->course_booking_model->change_mode($mode);

      if($query){
        $notification = "Success";
       }
      else{
       $notification = "Failed";
       }
  }
  catch(Exception $e){
    $notification = $e->getMessage();
  }
   echo json_encode(array('notify'=>$notification));

}
```

Edit:
The images you have uploaded indicate that there is a problem with the server-side code, and your button click is firing just fine. If you update your php to catch the error and return it, you should be able to get a hint as to what is going wrong. To see the call completing, you could implement the 'complete' and/or 'error' callbacks:

```
  $.ajax({

    type:"POST",
    url:"<?php echo base_url();?>superadmin/change_mode",
    dataType:'json',
    data:postdata,
    success: function(data){

         if(data.notify=="Success")
            {
             console.log(data.notify);
             location.reload();
            }
            else{
              console.log(data.notify);

            }

       },
    error: function(jqXhr, txtStatus, errThrown){
         console.log('Call failed with status:' + txtStatus);

         if(errThrown)
             console.log('and error:' + errThrown);
       },
    complete: function(jqXhr, txtStatus){   
         console.log('Call completed with status:' + txtStatus);
       }
  });

});
```

Comment: Take a look to the image I have uploaded when I added the  console.log('Posting mode_val: ' + mode_val); in the js function

Answer (score 0):

hmmm maybe something like this

```
$(".btn_mode[value='1']").on("click", function(){ do something });
$(".btn_mode[value='0']").on("dblclick", function(){ do something });
```

Comment: I think we have misunderstanding here :), I want the disable button to be clicked just once for it to work because now, it needs to be clicked twice before it works

Comment: ah right I understand now. When you click the disabled button nothing happens until you click it a second time.

Comment: Yes, absolutely. What is the problem with this? Please help

Comment: Yeah, but it works fine when just alerting the values but my javascript function would visit the controller and model function of codeigniter and echo json_encode then prints to the console

Comment: so it always return an alert on button click, on both buttons?

Comment: are you pushing the disable button after the enable button, i ask this because the js needs time to fire the ajax to the server.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change your model to return the real outcome of the update.
Like:

```
return $this->db->update('maintenance_mode',$data);
```

depending on what the db wrapper return after an update.